# MySQL JOIN a table, and then JOIN that new table to itself

Tags: php, mysql, join

First of all, I'm not proficient at all in SQL, so this is a monumental task, but here is what I got so far:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/289886/1)

As you can see, I've got a project management software project and I'm trying to build a report from it. Seems like mostly I'm getting the data i need, except that I can't get the Parent Task name.

Tasks table includes ids, names, etc, as well as a column specifically for a Parent Task Id. So it needs to be joined to itself so that I can get the name of that parent task. But in the same run, I'm starting from the timelogs table, and trying to join a bunch of other tables for other information.

In my production database, for example, I also have a company table that all of the projects have an id for, so I'm going to need to join those together at some point too.

So here's the QUESTION:

Why in that sqlfiddle up there, does the parent task name field not fill out for taskID 6? How do I get that info?

Comment: The SQL Fiddle seems to be having problems (or the site is). Can you post the schema and SQL statements you are using?

Comment: @SloanThrasher The link was broken: I fixed it

Comment: @FrankerZ Still isn't working for me either, neither of the fiddles, yours or mine are coming up. SQLFiddle seems to be having a problem. (even the about.html page isn't showing up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left join needs to join on the `pt` reference you set for tasks. Your join should look like so:

```
LEFT JOIN tasks pt ON tasks.parentTaskId = pt.taskId
```

See updated fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/289886/6).